# How to find words within cells of same style

Tags: front-end, menu

I have long notebook with several cells styles (Input, Output, Text, Section, Subsection,...), and I want to find words in the notebook only in the cells have same style.

It is very annoying when you have long notebook with same words in several cell styles and you want to find the words only in certain cell style.

For example, if I have the following notebook :

```
CreateDocument[{TextCell["test", "Section"], 
   ExpressionCell[test, "Input"], TextCell["test"], 
   TextCell["head one", "Section"], TextCell["test", "Section"], 
   ExpressionCell[Sin[x], "Input"]}];
```

How can I find the word `test` only in the `Section` style cells. If I use `Find (Ctrl+f)` and click `Find Next`, `Find` will search the next match wherever it is. I want the searching of the word to be only within `Section` style cells.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["test", "Section"], 
   ExpressionCell[test, "Input"], TextCell["test"], 
   TextCell["head one", "Section"], TextCell["test", "Section"], 
   ExpressionCell[Sin[x], "Input"]}]
```

---

You can use `NotebookFind` on a subset of cells.

```
If[SelectionMove[#, Before, Cell]; NotebookFind[#, "test"] =!= $Failed, 
   #, 
   Nothing
] & /@ Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]
```

[image]

Comment: That is great. can you tell me how can I access the content of certain cell through its `CellObject`. For example, if I want to access the content of the `Cell` associated to the first `CellObjec` in the `Out[47]` in your answer, what should I do? The idea is I want to filter the result of the `Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]` and get only those `CellObject` associated to Cells containing `"test"`.

Comment: @Algohi It is already done. As you can see only two cells are returned out of three.

Comment: Sorry,  my mistake. Thank you

Comment: @Algohi Great ;) tell my if you want to extend this or something. I don't have much time lately but I'm reading what's going on. Good luck.

Comment: Is there a way to not let the result depend on the current position of the cursor. I am getting some weird results where every `NotebookFind` gives `$Failed` depending on the position of the cursor. (I mean, I get the expected behaviour if the cursor is at the top of the notebook. If it is at the end all NotebookFind instances give `$Failed`.) From "If obj is a NotebookObject, then the find operation starts where the selection is in the notebook." I would have expected that the cursor position should not affect `CellObject` but it seems that it does.

Comment: @Kvothe I can't reproduce it and I am not sure what is going on because the code moves selection before each cell so it should not matter where it was at the beginning.

Comment: @Kuba, I am sorry to have bothered you. I misunderstood the purpose of `SelectionMove` and did not include it in my test.