# Making NotebookFind independent of cursor position

Tags: notebooks

When I go through the [basic example of NotebookFind](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookFind.html), `NotebookFind` will run correctly exactly once after creating the `nb`. If I run `NotebookFind[nb, "at"]` again it returns `$Failed`. If I create a new `nb` I can again run `NotebookFind` once with the correct output afterwards it will again output `$Failed`. If I create the `nb` and then run `NotebookFind[nb, "at"]` inside the newly opened notebook (which automatically runs in the same kernel) it again outputs `$Failed` even the first time.

The same happens going through the example in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105346/45020.

In general it seems that NotebookFind can only be used once per notebook which seems completely crazy so something else must be going on.

---

As pointed out by Syed the search starts at the position of the cursor and therefore returns $Failed if the cursor is a the end of the notebook. According to the documentation:

> If obj is a NotebookObject, then the find operation starts where the
> selection is in the notebook.

However, even when we apply NotebookFind to a CellObject as in the second linked example I find that the cursor position matters even when it is not located in the Cell on which we act. (If it is in an earlier Cell it works. If in a later it gives $Failed.

Is there a way to always start the search from the top of the nb independently of the position of the current selection?

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of `NotebookFind[nb, "at"]`. Have `nb` and your main window open side by side. It will find "at" three times and when it reaches the end of the file, it gives `$Failed`. Put the cursor at the beginning of `nb` and you can find "at" three times once again.

Comment: @Syed, thank you! It indeed works as you describe. I must have accidentally moved to the cursor to the end of the notebook when I tried before. I did not know that it would not search before the current selection. Is there a way to always search from the top?
Also how does this work with cells? According to the documentation "If obj is a NotebookObject, then the find operation starts where the selection is in the notebook."

Comment: My knowledge of notebooks is fragile to non-existent. Please modify and rephrase the post (as well as the title perhaps) to get quality answers. Thanks.

Comment: However, in the second example I link I find the following behaviour:
1.) I run the line to create the nb.
2.) I run `cells = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]`.
3.) I run `NotebookFind[#, "test"] & /@ cells`
This moves the kernel and gives the correct output. But if the cursor is past the cell (so no selection at all in the cell. It again fails.

Comment: @Syed. Okay thanks! I will.

Answer (score 1):

You must move the selection before doing the NotebookFind.

With the example from the help:

```
nb = CreateWindow[
   DocumentNotebook[{TextCell["fat cat", "Text", CellTags -> {"L1"}], 
     TextCell["on my hat", "Text", CellTags -> {"L2"}]}]];
```

We now move the selection before the start of the notebook and then execute the NotebookFind:

```
SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook]
NotebookFind[nb, "at"]
```

This can be repeated as many times as you like.